# How to get only the actual body content of a Email in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I want to read the content of a email using Ballerina Gmail package.Is there any built in mechanism to read only the actual body content of the email excluding the signature of the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the **readMessage** function of the connector which I believe you have already started using. It returns the Message type object upon successful reading of a message from Gmail API. The Message type in the response has a **plainTextBodyPart**, a **htmlBodyPart**, an array of **inlineImgParts** and an array of **msgAttachments**. Please refer to the API documentation [1] of the Gmail Connector.

The **plainTextBodyPart** is a **MessageBodyPart** type and it is the MIME Message Part of your email body which has the content type **text/plain**.

The **htmlBodyPart** is a **MessageBodyPart** type and it is the MIME Message Part of your email body which has the content type **text/html**.

The **inlineImgParts** is an array of **MessageBodyPart** types and it is the array of MIME Message Parts with inline images of your email which have the content type **image/any**.

The **msgAttachments** is an array of **MessageBodyPart** types and it is the array of MIME Message Parts of the message consisting of the attachments of your email.

So if you want to read only the actual body content of the email excluding email headers, you can directly access it via above **MessageBodyPart** types.

If your email has a HTML message body, then you can access the HTML mail body as follows.

```
var response = gmailEP->readMessage(userId, messageId);
match response {
    gmail:Message m => {
        gmail:MessageBodyPart htmlMsgBody = m.htmlBodyPart;
        string htmlBody = htmlMsgBody.body;
        io:println(htmlBody); 
        // Your html message body will be a base64 encoded string. 
        // You may need to decode it using an inbuild Ballerina library, for your use.
    }             
    gmail:GmailError e => io:println(e);
```

}

Please note that in general the messages in your Gmail mailbox would contain both  HTML and text message bodies unless it was sent to you or created by you as text/plain (by composing it in Plain text mode). So when you read such mail, it would have both plainTextBodyPart and htmlBodyPart. The body of plainTextBodyPart will have only text body without the HTML tags and the body of htmlBodyPart will have the whole HTML content of the message.

You can verify this by viewing your email message in original mode. (Log in and go to the UI of your Gmail Mailbox and click on the **:** (more) button the top right corner of the mail you wish to read, and click **Show Original**. You can view your whole message as a MIME Message with all the headers and MIME Message Parts.

In addition you can get any the attachments and inline images of your email using **inlineImgParts** and **msgAttachments**.

Let me know if you have any further concerns.

[1] https://central.ballerina.io/wso2/gmail#Message